# Numpy Manipulation for Image Processing

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy

I've created a script to shift the hue of an image around the colour wheel by any number of steps.

As you might imagine, when I import an image (using PIL) and convert it to a Numpy array, it is this shape: (x, y, (r,g,b)).

I convert this array from RGB to HSV colour space with the Skimage color module (after scaling the RGB values to the range [0,1.0]).

The trouble I am having is manipulation of only one of the HSV values (either H, S, or V) for all pixels. I'd like to efficiently add, multiply, or subtract any of these three dimensions for every 'pixel' in the array.

I have gotten it to work by splitting the HSV values into three separate arrays:
`h,s,v = np.dsplit(hsv,3)`

manipulating the array in the way I want:
`h_new = np.multiply(h,.33)`

and then reassembling the array:
`hsv_new = np.stack((h_new,s,v))`

This doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do this and so my question is:
How can I manipulate each of these dimensions without having to split the array into chunks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hsv[:,:,0] *= 0.33
```

modifies the `h` component of `hsv` inplace.

`hsv[:,:,0]` is a "basic slice" of `hsv` and as such, is a *view* of the original array.

---

```
h, s, v = np.dsplit(hsv, 3)
```

creates 3 new arrays, `h`, `s`, `v` which copy data from `hsv`. Modifying `h`, `s`, `v` does not affect `hsv`. So modifying `h` then requires rebuilding `hsv`. This is therefore slower.

---

For notational convenience, you could replace

```
h,s,v = np.dsplit(hsv, 3)
```

with

```
h, s, v = hsv[:,:,0], hsv[:,:,1], hsv[:,:,2]
```

Then `h`, `s`, `v` will be views of `hsv`, and modifying `h`, `s`, `v` will automatically affect `hsv` itself. (So there is no need for `hsv_new = np.stack((h_new,s,v))`).

---

Note also that `h,s,v = np.dsplit(hsv, 3)` makes `h`, `s` and `v` have shape `(n, m, 1)`. Whereas

```
h, s, v = hsv[:,:,0], hsv[:,:,1], hsv[:,:,2]
```

makes `h`, `s` and `v` have shape `(n, m)`. That might affect your other code a little bit, but overall I think the latter is nicer.

Comment: excellent! Thanks!
I was particularly confused earlier when trying to do something similar but with notation `hsv[:][:][0]`. Do you, by chance, do you know the difference between `hsv[:][:][0]` and `hsv[:,:,0]`?

Comment: `hsv[:]` is a view of the entire array `hsv`. They are not the same objects in the sense that `hsv[:] is not hsv`, but they share the same underlying data. `hsv[:].shape` is the same as `hsv.shape`. Same story for `hsv[:][:]`. Look at the shapes and all should be clear.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to accept this answer. Apparently back in the day I didn't know this was possible (or maybe this feature is newer than this answer?!)